# Laravel : orWhere Search query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a simple query in my model to get data. Now I want to search with `companyname`.My query code:

```
 $searchablePost    = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
                     ->whereIn('status',$is_or_active)
                     ->whereIn('product_id', $userApprovalProductIDs)
                     ->whereIn('demand_or_supply', $is_demand_supply)
                     ->offset($offset)->limit($limit)
                     ->orderBy('id','desc');
```

Now, I got `6 rows` in this `6 rows` I want to filter data with `companyname` which i get with comma separated `abcCompany,indCompany`.

```
array:2 [
  0 => "abccompany"
  1 => "indcompany"
]
```

What I try :

```
  if($companyname !="") {
        $companyDetail    = Explode(',',$companyname);
        $searchablePost->whereHas('user.userDetails', function ($query) use ($companyDetail) {
                $i=1;
                foreach ($companyDetail as $search_with_compayname) {
                        if(count($companyDetail)>0 && $i==1) {
                            $query->where('company','LIKE',"%{$search_with_compayname}%");
                        } else {
                            $query->orWhere('company','LIKE',"%{$search_with_compayname}%");
                        }
                $i++;
                }
        });
    }
```

Is it good or is there any other way to good search ?

Comment: care to show your model?

Comment: You could have gone for `whereIn('company', $companyDetail)` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search a CSV list of company names, MySQL makes available a function `FIND_IN_SET`.  I think you can just add a `whereRaw` clause to your current Laravel query:

```
 $searchablePost = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
    ->whereIn('status', $is_or_active)
    ->whereIn('product_id', $userApprovalProductIDs)
    ->whereIn('demand_or_supply', $is_demand_supply)
    ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(company, ?) > 0', [$search_with_compayname])
    ->offset($offset)
    ->limit($limit)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
```

While the above may work, the best long term approach is to avoid CSV and other unnormalized data in your database.  Ideally, you would have a table containing the list of company names, with one name on each record.  Then, you could join or use an `EXISTS` query to answer your question.

Comment: Can  we do this in separate query because there is other serach on same query.?

Comment: @Javed You can apply the `whereRaw` code I gave above to any query where there is a `company` column and it would make sense.  I tried to modify your existing query, because I thought that was the question.

Comment: it is not working `LIKE` , I want it work as `LIKE` query.

Comment: @Javed No.  Then you should fix your data model and stop trying to do complex operations against a comma separated string.

Comment: But on a search box user can search with `multiple companyname` , suggest me some good idea.

Comment: Your premise doesn't make sense to me.  If you control the company options presented to the user (because you know beforehand what is in the DB), then why can't you use an exact match?